# Make heap with vector

Tags: c++, algorithm

There are two ways i can think:

1. make_heap(v.begin(), v.end()
2. priority_queue<int, vector> (v.begin(), v.end()

Would both have on O(n) time complexity for heapify?

Thanks

Comment: What does the [documentation say](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)?

Comment: Do you mean that: you will build a heap from a vector of `n` elements with `O(n)` time complexity in total?